# Can startMonitoringForRegion wake my app up, and start gps tracking?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, background-process, regions

In Apple's developer portal , it states that startMonitoringForRegion:desiredAccuracy: will eventually wake up my app (even if it's killed) and send the Core location delegate a message.

The question is : Is it possible to start GPS tracking (precise tracking, instead of cell-tower based tracking) after receiving this message (even if my app is in the background ) ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well , I searched for it , and it appears as it does wake up the app.
I can also use `startUpdatingLocation` to get more frequent (and even GPS) updates.